# exec python script and mock missing modules

Tags: python, python-3.x, mocking

I am running a execfile() on python script but in this script there are calls to modules that I don't have. I would therefore like to replace them with fakeObject/mock

I have this instruction:

```
import mymodule.mtest.core as CCORE
API = CCORE.object()
API.initialize(sys.argv, comm=comm)
```

But i dont have **mymodule.mtest.core** and i want to replace **CCORE.object()** with a fake object
containing the initialize() method

I tried someting like this:

```
sys.modules['mymodule'] = MyfakeObj
```

With MyFakeObj is a python module with a fake def initialiaze() method

But i have this error

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mymodule.mtest'; 'mymodule' is not a
> package

How can i do this ?

Comment: Are you allowed to change the script itself?

Comment: i can't change the input script

Comment: So I doubt that changing `sys.modules` outside of this script could make any difference.

Comment: it works for other module which are not on package. For example "import bidule" works if i set sys.modules["bidule"]=FakeObject before doing exec on my script contening the import instruction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thank you for your help. I tested your proposal but in my context the instructions

```
ith patch.object(mymodule.mtest.core, "object", return_value=Mock()):
```

does not works,

on the other hand it put me on the track to use Mock()

I use like this:

```
sys.modules['mymodule'] = MagicMock()
sys.modules['mymodule.mtest'] = MagicMock()
sys.modules['mymodule.mtest.core'] = MagicMock()
```

And i can exec my script with the instructions

```
import mymodule.mtest.core
```

the import no longer crashes

Answer (score 1):

You can patch/mock objects using [`unittest.mock`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html). But because `unittest` was created for testing purposes, I'm really not sure if you should use it.

```py
from unittest.mock import Mock, patch

with patch("mymodule.mtest.core"):
    execfile() # What you want to run
```

If you want to get custom value from `mymodule.mtest.core` attribute or method:

```py
from unittest.mock import Mock, patch

with patch("mymodule.mtest.core") as mocked_function:
    mocked_function = Mock()
    mocked_function.some_attribute= "something"
    mocked_function.some_method = Mock(return_value="something")
    execfile() # What you want to run
```

Comment: I mixed use of `patch` and `patch.object`. I fixed my answer but I thing your answer is a better way to do it